# How to view cities name if I saved it as ID in laravel?

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have three table: **users**,**interviews** & **cities**.

I am saving city ID's in **user** table city field.
I am trying to fetch users city field in interview's section and i am getting all users data such as name, age, mobile etc. but I'm getting only city ID not city name.

My interview model relationship:

```
public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
    }
```

My controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $user_id= Auth::user()->id;
        $items= Interviews::where('user_id',$user_id)->where('status','>=',1)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
        return view('frontend.index',compact('items'));
    }
```

My view

```
@foreach($items as $i => $item)
        <!-- Item #1 -->
            <tr>
                    <td><b> {{ $item->id}}</td>
                    <td><b>{{ $item->User['name']}}</td> 
                    <td><b> {{ $item->User['city']}}</td>
                    <td><b> {{ $item->interview_date}}</td>

            </tr>                            
@endforeach
```

Comment: what are the columns in Interviews table?

Comment: I have id, user_id  result_id , interview_date and etc

Comment: according to your query, you have only taken values from the table Interviews, and you have not even joined Users or Cities. I don't see how you can even get the name of the User from the above query.

Comment: Can you please help me??

Comment: But i am getting users name  due to relationship and city also but city is in id not its value

Comment: Do you have a similar relationship in the User table with City table?